# Copying values to a separate Excel Sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, copy

I have `code` that auto-copies specific `cells` from a master `sheet` into another `sheet`. This is achieved when a specific `value` is entered into `Column B`.

For the example below, I want to copy all `cells` where the `value` in `Column B` is equal to `Faults Raised`. The issue I'm having is the master `sheet` has a separate `script` that hides/unhides `columns` based on other various `'values'` entered into `Column B`.

When `Faults Raised` is entered, `Columns B:C, AC:AE, BP` are shown. But when I try to auto-copy across only `Column B` is shown. I can't get `C, AC:AE` and `BP` to copy across? What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

  Set sht1 = Sheets("SHIFT LOG")
  Set sht2 = Sheets("FAULTS RAISED")

  sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents
  Dim rng As Range

  With sht1.Cells(2, "B").CurrentRegion
      .Range("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns
      .AutoFilter
      .AutoFilter 2, "Faults Raised"
      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht2.Cells(6, 2)
      .AutoFilter

      .Range("C:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
      sht2.Range("C:AA").EntireColumn.Delete ' delete 'sht2' columns
      .Range("AE:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
      sht2.Range("AE:BN").EntireColumn.Delete ' delete 'sht2' columns
  End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Within sht1.Columns("B:BP").CurrentRegion either .Range("B:BP").EntireColumn is wrong addressing or .AutoFilter field:=1 is referring to column A. Why not sht1.Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion ?

Comment: I need it to get entered into column 2, row 6 on sheet 2. The auto filter is wrong. So my referring column is wrong. It should be B. I've altered this but it's still the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .CurrentRegion is fouling up the area that you want to work within. Within sht1.Columns("B:BP").CurrentRegion either .Range("B:BP").EntireColumn is wrong addressing or .AutoFilter field:=1 is referring to column A.  Intersect can help to overcome a couple of these problems.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("SHIFT LOG")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("FAULTS RAISED")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        'within B:BP, column B is the first column
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Faults Raised"
        'within B:BP, Columns B:C, AC:AE, BP are referenced as .Columns A:B, AB:AD, BO
        .Range("A:B, AB:AD, BO:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(6, "B")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        'no need to delete what was never there
        'within B:BP, Columns C:AA, AE:BN, BP are referenced as .Columns B:Z, AD:BM
        .Range("B:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
        .Range("AD:BM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting an error on the Intersect line though. It's saying the range failed

Comment: There are two intersect lines.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. Getting another error with the auto filter line. Method AtuoFilter of object Range failed

Comment: I'm just copying your code into the editor and returning the error?

Comment: I found a small syntax error in .Range("A:B, AB:AD, BO:BO") see edit above.

Comment: Just a quick question @Jeeped. What if the Master sheet was a table instead of range. Would this be possible? Would it require completely different code?